# Downsampling without smoothing

Tags: opencv

Is there a built-in way to downsample an image in OpenCV 2.3.1 without prior Gaussian smoothing (which is performed by pyrDown C++ function).

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [resize()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d).

```
# Python code:
import cv2
large_img = cv2.imread('our_large_image.jpg')
small_to_large_image_size_ratio = 0.2
small_img = cv2.resize(large_img, # original image
                       (0,0), # set fx and fy, not the final size
                       fx=small_to_large_image_size_ratio, 
                       fy=small_to_large_image_size_ratio, 
                       interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Instead of `interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST` you can use any of [these interpolation methods](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

Answer (score 0):

resize() with interpolation= INTER_NEAREST.

**EDIT**

hmmm, what if you write the function yourself?

```
double factor;
int newcols = round(mat.cols*factor);
int newrows = round(mat.rows*factor);

Mat newmat = Mat(newcol, newrows, mat.type());

for (int i=0;i<mat.cols;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<mat.cols;j++){
        newmat_<yourtype> (round(i*factor), round(j*factor)) = mat_<yourtype>(i, j);
    }
}
```

I haven't checked whether the code works or not (most likely not), but you get the idea.

Comment: More specifically, I'd like to throw away all even rows and columns. Unfortunately, your suggestion spits a lot of BUUUs:

`template<class T>
Mat_<T> DownsampleFromGrid8ToGrid16(Mat_<T>& x)
{
 Mat_<T> res(Size(x.cols/2, x.rows/2));
 for(int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < x.cols; j++)
   if(i%2 == 1 && j%2 == 1)
    res(i/2,j/2) = x(i,j);
 Mat_<T> tmp;
 resize(x, tmp, Size(res.cols, res.rows), 0, 0, INTER_NEAREST);
 for(int i = 0; i < res.rows; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < res.cols; j++)
  {
   T tt=res(i,j);
   T ttt=tmp(i,j);
   if(tt != ttt)
    puts("BUUU");
  }
 return res;
}`

Answer (score -5):

You can use Image Pyramids: pyrDown, the links of the opencv document is 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The question specifically asks for without smoothing and mentions pyrDown as a counter example. Unless you include explanation for how pyrDown can be used to downsample without smoothing, this doesn't answer the question.