# cv::Mat.data always returns the same value

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have a red image - just for testing. The RGB Color is (217/18/36).

I perform the following code:

```
void QuaterImage(Mat& SrcImage, Mat& DestImage, bool Downsample) {
    int newWidth = 0, newHeight = 0;
    int newOrigWidth = 0, newOrigHeight = 0;

    if (SrcImage.cols % 2 > 0) { newOrigWidth = SrcImage.cols - 1; } else { newOrigWidth = SrcImage.cols; }
    if (SrcImage.rows % 2 > 0) { newOrigHeight = SrcImage.rows - 1; } else { newOrigHeight = SrcImage.rows; }

    if (SrcImage.depth() != CV_8U) { return; }

    newHeight = newOrigHeight / 2;
    newWidth = newOrigWidth / 2;

    DestImage = Mat(newWidth, newHeight, SrcImage.type());
    int r = 0, c = 0;
    uchar* DataPtr = SrcImage.ptr<uchar>(0);

    std::cout << std::to_string(*DataPtr) << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

It always returns "205".

If I change the image to be complettely yellow, it returns the exact same value. How can that be?

Regards,
Jan

Comment: you only consider the first byte of the bmp, is really what you want ?

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Here you're redefining `SrcImage`

Comment: Hi, postet the complette function. I know, I'm currently only accessing the first byte. And thats not, what I want - but currently, I'm searching for the error... If thats fixed, I'll continue. In the end, I like to design a function which can downsample an image bei half of the width and half of the hight as fast as possible. therefor I only want to take the average of four pixel for one pixel in the cores image.

Comment: no, I only cut the part, where I calculate the new width and new hight. You can delete that part, because it's not used until now. The assigning of the pointer and the output is exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe you just want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431919/downsampling-without-smoothing

Comment: something like that, but first I would like to know, where my mistake is...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, I got it. You could not see it. I was giving the same image for `SrcImage` and `DestImage`, so the line `DestImage = Mat(newWidth, newHeight, SrcImage.type());`overwrote the image. Before that line, the values are correct.

Sorry for that...

Comment: for future errors, it is Mat(height, width, ...) order